# Problema em gerar gráfico de colunas agrupadas no R

Tags: r, gráfico

Olá! Estou com um problema para gerar um gráfico no R.

Gostaria de fazer um gráfico de colunas agrupadas utilizando os seguintes dados descritos na imagem abaixo.

No caso os bits seriam para cada um dos 9 pontos (P1, P2 ... P3), sendo a coleta 1 agrupado com coleta 2.

Gostaria que estivesse assim no eixo X: P1 (colunas P1 da coleta 1 e da coleta 2) e assim por diante até P9 (colunas P1 da coleta 1 e da coleta 2)

Obrigado!

[image: Imagem 1]

Os valores eu adicionei da seguinte forma, sei que não é a mais prática:
riq1<-scan()
7
2
3
3
2
4
3
4
4

riq2<-scan()
4
5
6
5
6
6
6
6
4

Answer (score 2):

Eis duas soluções, R base e pacote `ggplot2`.

### 1. Os dados

A leitura dos dados pode ser feita com `textConnection` e `scan`.

```
txt <- "7 2 3 3 2 4 3 4 4"
riq1 <- scan(textConnection(txt))
txt <- "4 5 6 5 6 6 6 6 4"
riq2 <- scan(textConnection(txt))
dados <- data.frame(riq1, riq2)
```

### 2. R base

Com a função `barplot` é muito simples traçar um gráfico de barras. Basta saber que deve ser usada a transposta da tabela.

```
barplot(t(dados), beside=TRUE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Pacote `ggplot`.

Este tipo de problema geralmente está relacionado à reformatação dos dados. O formato deve ser longo e os dados estão em formato largo. Veja [esta postagem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) sobre como reformatar os dados do formato largo para o longo.

```
library(ggplot2)

dados |>
  dplyr::mutate(P = dplyr::row_number()) |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-P) |>
  ggplot(aes(P, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]